# Android Application java lang exception

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have created an android application using Android Studio IDE while clicking the button in my app it does'nt navigate it to the another activity instead its throwing up the exception

Here is My Logcat:

```
        02-10 11:33:56.030    7404-7404/com.example.mcs.oodoeg E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                    at org.apache.xmlrpc.common.XmlRpcController.<init>(XmlRpcController.java:31)
                    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.<init>(XmlRpcClient.java:51)
                    at com.example.mcs.oodoeg.MainActivity.getXmlRpcClient(MainActivity.java:138)
                    at com.example.mcs.oodoeg.MainActivity.registerUser(MainActivity.java:103)
                    at com.example.mcs.oodoeg.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:45)
                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4275)
                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17434)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
             Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                    at org.apache.xmlrpc.common.TypeFactoryImpl.<clinit>(TypeFactoryImpl.java:88)
                    at org.apache.xmlrpc.common.XmlRpcController.<init>(XmlRpcController.java:31)
                    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.<init>(XmlRpcClient.java:51)
                    at com.example.mcs.oodoeg.MainActivity.getXmlRpcClient(MainActivity.java:138)
                    at com.example.mcs.oodoeg.MainActivity.registerUser(MainActivity.java:103)
                    at com.example.mcs.oodoeg.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:45)
                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4275)
                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17434)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
             Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.ws.commons.serialize.DOMSerializer
                    at org.apache.xmlrpc.serializer.NodeSerializer.<clinit>(NodeSerializer.java:30)
                    at org.apache.xmlrpc.common.TypeFactoryImpl.<clinit>(TypeFactoryImpl.java:88)
                    at org.apache.xmlrpc.common.XmlRpcController.<init>(XmlRpcController.java:31)
                    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.<init>(XmlRpcClient.java:51)
                    at com.example.mcs.oodoeg.MainActivity.getXmlRpcClient(MainActivity.java:138)
                    at com.example.mcs.oodoeg.MainActivity.registerUser(MainActivity.java:103)
                    at com.example.mcs.oodoeg.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:45)
                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4275)
                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17434)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my  Main Activity class i have created two buttons here called register and signin:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn;

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intObj = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intObj);

        }
    });
    Button btn2;
    btn2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Sigin.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } );
}
```

When the register button is clicked this  Main Activity2 should be called:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.next);
    }
```

When sigin button is clicked this sigin class should be called:

```
public class Sigin extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sigin);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your source code

Comment: It is throwing `NoClassDefFoundError`. Do you have correct jars in classpath?

Comment: Yes i have my jars in correct classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are  missing ws-commons-util-1.0.2.jar from $EXIST_HOME/lib/core.

You have to make sure you have included at least all of the libraries from $EXIST_HOME/lib/core.